# How to deploy an atg project in weblogic?

Tags: weblogic, atg

I created a simple project using ATG 10.2 .I want to know how to deploy it in weblogic. Please provide detailed procedure with screenshots,if possible.

Answer (score 2):

To provide a 'detailed' procedure is beyond the scope of what StackOverflow is trying to provide. That said, if you have an understanding of the Weblogic Management Console you should be able to follow these steps to setup your initial deployment:

1. Create a Server

   1.1 Specify a server name (eg. commerce) and the port number this server will run on (eg. 8180). Select it as a 'Stand-alone server'.

   1.2 Once created go to Configuration > Server Start for the newly created server and modify the 'Arguments' block and include the following setings (assuming you are running windows, for Unix update your own paths)

   ```
   -Datg.dynamo.data-dir=c:\ATG-Data -Datg.dynamo.server.name=commerce -d64 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Xms1152m -Xmx2048m -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
   ```

   1.3 Save your Server
2. Create DataSources

   2.1 In the Console click on 'Services > Data Sources'

   2.2 Create 'New' datasources for each of your connections. As a minimum you will need connections for `ATGSwitchingDS_A`, `ATGSwitchingDS_B` (Assuming you are doing switching datasources) and `ATGProductionDS`. These names should match your JNDI names in your property files. Remember to specify the 'commerce' server as the target for each of the datasources.
3. Create Deployment

   3.1 Assuming you've already built your EAR (eg. ATGProduction.ear) and it is available in `c:\deployments` you need to create a deployment in Weblogic. You need to create the deployment in the console and specify the target as 'commerce'. Once done you need to also 'start serving requests' on the deployment.
4. Start Server

You should now be able to see your server running on port 8180 with the log files being written to `c:\ATG-Data\servers\commerce\logs`.

If after this things aren't running, post specific questions about your issues and someone here might be able to help you.

Comment: I did same way but getting the following errors.                                                      Error 500--Internal Server Error

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at atg.userdirectory.account.AccountUserDirectory.getPrincipal(AccountUserDirectory.java:184)
 at atg.userdirectory.account.AccountUserDirectory.findUserByPrimaryKey(AccountUserDirectory.java:240)
 at atg.userdirectory.account.AccountUserDirectory.findUserByLogin(AccountUserDirectory.java:261)
 at 
 at atg.servlet.pipeline.UserAuthorityAuthenticator.authenticate(UserAuthorityAuthenticator.java:373)
 at  .................